# Where is PHP executable setting in PhpStorm 2020.3?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I am trying to configure Xdebug 3. In the documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#integrationWithProduct they show

[image]

But I cannot find this field.

Or how to configure Xdebug 3 it would be enough answer for me.

Comment: Here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-interpreters.html -- the path to that settings screen is at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I turn out I was there but needed to click 3 dots button which I did not see because dialog was too small. There was a scrollbar which I did not notice

[image]